# cronjob r script in Centos

Tags: r, centos

I have got an r-script on this location (Centos7) : /home/admin/R/devel
When using a cronjob I can not get it to work. How do I initialize the R-script?

```
18  16-20   *   *   *   /usr/lib64/R/bin/R /home/admin/R/devel/scrape_snh.R
```

Comment: We have no idea what errors you are seeing so how can we possibly render aid?

Comment: where should i look for errors?

Comment: this is the location of R: /usr/lib64/R

Comment: Does the command work in the shell?

Comment: the r-script has the correct rights. This is the part i am not sure about /usr/lib64/R/bin/R. especially the last bit.

Comment: the problem was the cran mirror